# No backend configured for scheme https

Tags: perl, paypal

anyone can help. am getting that error

Error: No backend configured for scheme https

```
my $http = HTTP::Tinyish->new();


 my $res = $http->post("https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token/", {
      headers => { 'username' => 'client_id',
                   'password' => 'screte',
                   'grant_type' => 'client_credentials'}
  });

  $http->get("https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-5YK922393D847794YKER7MUI", {
      headers => { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' },
  });



  if ( $res->{'is_success'} ) {
  print Dumper( decode_json $res->{'content'} );
} else {
  print "$res->{'status'} $res->{'reason'}\n";
}
```

Comment: Please check [the documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Tinyish) and make sure that you have any of the backends described installed. If you do then add the relevant information to your question, i.e. which backend is installed in your opinion and how did you verify this.

Comment: Crossposted to https://perlmonks.org/?node_id=1225025

Answer (score 5):

`HTTP::Tinyish` is a frontend to `HTTP::Tiny`, libwww-perl and the command-line tools `curl` and `wget`. It picks one that is available based on the URL scheme.

The two Perl modules do not support TLS out of the box . My guess is therefore that you neither have `curl` nor `wget` installed, and your libwww-perl does not support TLS.

So you may be able to fix your problem by installing either `curl`, `LWP::Protocol::https` or both.

Comment: No - for libwww-perl, install LWP::Protocol::https https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::Protocol::https , not Net::SSLeay, as that will not be enough. LWP::Protocol::https then pulls in Net::SSLeay

Comment: When running `plenv install -l` I got a `No backend configured for scheme https` too. Installing `HTTP::Tinyish`, then `LWP::Protocol::https` fixed my problem. Make sure they're installed by re-running the install command and verifying you get the "Already installed" message.